# Homebrew elasticsearch/kibana installation is failing

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, homebrew, kibana, macos-ventura

I have updated to macOS ventura, there was some issue with ES(v7.17.4) so I uninstalled it and now when I'm trying to re-install the same, running into below error.

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification_policy.rb:4:in '<top (required)>': superclass mismatch for class SpecificationPolicy (TypeError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in 'require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in 'require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:16:in '<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:1365:in '<module:Gem>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:116:in '<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in 'require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in 'require'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils/gems.rb:47:in 'setup_gem_environment!'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/standalone/load_path.rb:13:in '<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/startup.rb:6:in 'require_relative'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/startup.rb:6:in '<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:4:in 'require_relative'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:4:in '<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb:11:in 'require_relative'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb:11:in '<main>'
Error: Failure while executing; `/usr/bin/sandbox-exec -f /private/tmp/homebrew20221031-58137-1t7tz3a.sb nice /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -W1 -- /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/elastic/homebrew-tap/Formula/elasticsearch-full.rb --debug` exited with 1.
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/sandbox.rb:157:in 'exec'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formula_installer.rb:917:in 'block in build'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils/fork.rb:45:in 'block (3 levels) in safe_fork'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils/fork.rb:37:in 'fork'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils/fork.rb:37:in 'block (2 levels) in safe_fork'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils/fork.rb:34:in 'open'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils/fork.rb:34:in 'block in safe_fork'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tmpdir.rb:93:in 'mktmpdir'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils/fork.rb:33:in 'safe_fork'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formula_installer.rb:905:in 'build'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formula_installer.rb:450:in 'install'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/upgrade.rb:203:in 'install_formula'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/install.rb:350:in 'install_formula'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/install.rb:340:in 'block in install_formulae'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/install.rb:339:in 'each'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/install.rb:339:in 'install_formulae'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/install.rb:233:in 'install'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:95:in '<main>'
```

Tried couple of solutions, found here and there on the Internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my answer at [superclass mismatch for class SpecificationPolicy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74294323/superclass-mismatch-for-class-specificationpolicy), what I did to help me overcome what looks like the same error