# superclass mismatch for class SpecificationPolicy

Tags: ruby, xcode, macos, homebrew

I'm getting a `superclass mismatch for class SpecificationPolicy` error when trying to install or upgrade certain brew packages.

For example, when updating installing the supabase CLI (`brew install supabase/tap/supabase`):

```
==> Installing supabase from supabase/tap
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:12: warning: already initialized constant Gem::VERSION
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:11: warning: previous definition of VERSION was here
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/compatibility.rb:14: warning: already initialized constant Gem::RubyGemsVersion
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/compatibility.rb:15: warning: previous definition of RubyGemsVersion was here
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/compatibility.rb:18: warning: already initialized constant Gem::RbConfigPriorities
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/compatibility.rb:18: warning: previous definition of RbConfigPriorities was here
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/compatibility.rb:27: warning: constant Gem::ConfigMap is deprecated
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/compatibility.rb:35: warning: constant Gem::ConfigMap is deprecated
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/defaults.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant Gem::DEFAULT_HOST
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/defaults.rb:3: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_HOST was here
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:117: warning: already initialized constant Gem::RUBYGEMS_DIR
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:115: warning: previous definition of RUBYGEMS_DIR was here
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:122: warning: already initialized constant Gem::WIN_PATTERNS
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:129: warning: previous definition of WIN_PATTERNS was here
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:131: warning: already initialized constant Gem::GEM_DEP_FILES
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:138: warning: previous definition of GEM_DEP_FILES was here
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:141: warning: already initialized constant Gem::REPOSITORY_SUBDIRECTORIES
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:148: warning: previous definition of REPOSITORY_SUBDIRECTORIES was here
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:153: warning: already initialized constant Gem::REPOSITORY_DEFAULT_GEM_SUBDIRECTORIES
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:161: warning: previous definition of REPOSITORY_DEFAULT_GEM_SUBDIRECTORIES was here
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:162: warning: already initialized constant Gem::READ_BINARY_ERRORS
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:169: warning: previous definition of READ_BINARY_ERRORS was here
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:172: warning: already initialized constant Gem::WRITE_BINARY_ERRORS
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:174: warning: previous definition of WRITE_BINARY_ERRORS was here
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:185: warning: already initialized constant Gem::LOADED_SPECS_MUTEX
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:181: warning: previous definition of LOADED_SPECS_MUTEX was here
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:1345: warning: already initialized constant Gem::MARSHAL_SPEC_DIR
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:1319: warning: previous definition of MARSHAL_SPEC_DIR was here
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/version.rb:157: warning: already initialized constant Gem::Version::VERSION_PATTERN
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/version.rb:157: warning: previous definition of VERSION_PATTERN was here
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/version.rb:158: warning: already initialized constant Gem::Version::ANCHORED_VERSION_PATTERN
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/version.rb:158: warning: previous definition of ANCHORED_VERSION_PATTERN was here
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/requirement.rb:17: warning: already initialized constant Gem::Requirement::OPS
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/requirement.rb:12: warning: previous definition of OPS was here
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/requirement.rb:27: warning: already initialized constant Gem::Requirement::SOURCE_SET_REQUIREMENT
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/requirement.rb:22: warning: previous definition of SOURCE_SET_REQUIREMENT was here
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/requirement.rb:30: warning: already initialized constant Gem::Requirement::PATTERN_RAW
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/requirement.rb:25: warning: previous definition of PATTERN_RAW was here
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/requirement.rb:35: warning: already initialized constant Gem::Requirement::PATTERN
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/requirement.rb:30: warning: previous definition of PATTERN was here
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/requirement.rb:40: warning: already initialized constant Gem::Requirement::DefaultRequirement
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/requirement.rb:35: warning: previous definition of DefaultRequirement was here
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/requirement.rb:314: warning: already initialized constant Gem::Version::Requirement
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/requirement.rb:311: warning: previous definition of Requirement was here
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/platform.rb:198: warning: already initialized constant Gem::Platform::RUBY
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/platform.rb:204: warning: previous definition of RUBY was here
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/platform.rb:204: warning: already initialized constant Gem::Platform::CURRENT
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/platform.rb:210: warning: previous definition of CURRENT was here
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:9: warning: already initialized constant Gem::StubSpecification::PREFIX
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:9: warning: previous definition of PREFIX was here
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:12: warning: already initialized constant Gem::StubSpecification::OPEN_MODE
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:12: warning: previous definition of OPEN_MODE was here
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:18: warning: already initialized constant Gem::StubSpecification::StubLine::NO_EXTENSIONS
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:18: warning: previous definition of NO_EXTENSIONS was here
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:21: warning: already initialized constant Gem::StubSpecification::StubLine::REQUIRE_PATHS
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:21: warning: previous definition of REQUIRE_PATHS was here
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:31: warning: already initialized constant Gem::StubSpecification::StubLine::REQUIRE_PATH_LIST
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:31: warning: previous definition of REQUIRE_PATH_LIST was here
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification_policy.rb:4:in `<top (required)>': superclass mismatch for class SpecificationPolicy (TypeError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:1365:in `<module:Gem>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:116:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils/gems.rb:47:in `setup_gem_environment!'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/standalone/load_path.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/startup.rb:6:in `require_relative'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/startup.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:4:in `require_relative'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb:11:in `require_relative'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb:11:in `<main>'
Error: Failure while executing; `/usr/bin/sandbox-exec -f /private/tmp/homebrew20221102-2820-wkxj9g.sb nice /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -W1 -- /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/supabase/homebrew-tap/supabase.rb` exited with 1.
```

I noticed that this error also occurs when doing a `brew upgrade` on a different library, `brew upgrade heroku`.

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification_policy.rb:4:in `<top (required)>': superclass mismatch for class SpecificationPolicy (TypeError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:1365:in `<module:Gem>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:116:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils/gems.rb:47:in `setup_gem_environment!'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/standalone/load_path.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/startup.rb:6:in `require_relative'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/startup.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:4:in `require_relative'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb:11:in `require_relative'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb:11:in `<main>'
Error: Failure while executing; `/usr/bin/sandbox-exec -f /private/tmp/homebrew20221102-5824-12bp753.sb nice /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -W1 -- /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/heroku/homebrew-brew/Formula/heroku-node.rb` exited with 1.
```

I'm using rvm to manage my ruby versions and `which ruby` gives `/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/bin/ruby`. So not sure where the "Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6" in the error log is coming from.

Seems like an issue between Homebrew and ruby. May be related to the most recent xcode and MacOS Ventura updates (other reports of this error [here](https://github.com/railwayapp/nixpacks/issues/633) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74258924/homebrew-elasticsearch-kibana-installation-is-failing))?

Anyone have any ideas or get past this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I came across [this](https://gist.github.com/claui/3fb9f66bc2cfdecd0c33c3f976cc6125), which suggested that to "clean up system Ruby properly", one could run:

```
sudo rm -rf \
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/{build_info,cache,doc,extensions,gems} \
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/specifications/*.gemspec \
  /Library/Ruby/Site
```

I did this, re-ran the `brew` commands above, and the error was gone!

Not sure exactly what happened, maybe upgrading xcode and/or to MacOS Ventura messed with the system Ruby installation, which the above commands "clean up". It's also unclear why `which ruby` pointed to the updated ruby version installed by rvm, yet installing certain packages via Homebrew seemed to be invoking Mac's system Ruby (2.6.0).

Comment: Confirmed, this also resolves the problem for me on macOS Monterey with Xcode Command Line Tools software update 14.1 that was released recently.